# LPC4088 - JTAG dilemma

Tags: lpc

I have been trying to make a LPC4088 ([user manual](https://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10562.pdf), [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC408X_7X.pdf)) PCB for some time now and I have a dilemma concerning a JTAG. For connecting a 20-pin JTAG connector I followed the pinning table found on p. 358, 359 of [technical reference manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0314h/DDI0314H_coresight_components_trm.pdf) by ARM itself:

[image]
[image]

After this I located the pins with same functionalities on LPC4088 and I planned JTAG interface like this:

[image]

And now the problem occurred. While pins `JTAG_TDO`, `JTAG_TDI`, `JTAG_ TMS`, `JTAG_TRST`, `JTAG_TCK`, `RESET` are not problematic because they are pins with a single functionality:

[image]

while pins:

- `P2[5]` (has function `TD0`),
- `P2[4]` (has function `TD1`),
- `P2[3]` (has function `TD2`),
- `P2[2]` (has function `TD3`),
- `P2[6]` (has function `TCLK`)

are weird, because they have many functionalities and are by default set to be **GPIO**:

[image]
[image]

So how am I supposed to upload a program using JTAG if pins which have basic JTAG functionalities use different functionalities at reset? Are these pins even necessary for uploading or are they used only for debugging? In this case thing is fixable...

Comment: Usually when you are programming a chip, it is not supposed to do anything else. Once you disconnect JTAG, you can use the alternate functionality of the pins. Yes, there will be some problems with debugging over the JTAG. And this is why you are as the designer should think ahead and plan accordingly.

Comment: TRACEDATA is an "extra" and not part of the core 6-wire JTAG interface or 2-wire "single-wire" SWD interface. You can load a program over the 6 JTAG wires.

Comment: @pjc50 So my assumption was correct? `TD0`, `TD1`, `TD2`, `TD3`, `TCLK` are not really needed to inject a program into ARM core?